# Find ODE from given solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I know this is an easy question. However, I need a little bit of help to start.
If $e^{3x}$ and $e^{-x}$ are solutions of a second order constant coefficient linear homogeneous ode, what is the ode?

Comment: Why don't you just start? You know that the ODE looks like $y'' + ay'+ by = 0$. Now put in your functions for $y$ and determine the values of $a$ and $b$ from the resulting linear system.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $3$ and $-1$ are roots of what quadratic equation?

Answer (score 1):

We want to look for solutions of the form $y=ce^{\lambda x}$.

Subbing this into the general ODE of the form $y'' + ay'+by=0$ gives

$$ (\lambda^2 + a\lambda +b)ce^\lambda = 0$$

But of course $ce^\lambda \neq 0$, so we have

$$\lambda^2 + a\lambda +b = 0\tag{1}$$

where $\lambda = -1,3$.

Subbing in $\lambda = 3,-1$ into $(1)$ gives

$$ 3a+b=-9$$

and

$$ a-b=1$$

Solving gives $$ a=-2,  b=-3$$